# Storing office Templates with deployable C# application

Tags: c#, templates, deployment, ms-office

I have a c# application which manipulates an excel template, an access database, and other template (office type product). This all works fine when the templates are stored locally. However when I go to deploy my application (wanting to use clickonce) I need to know

1. where to store these templates (what folder to put them in in my project) so that they are installed with my application
2. how to access these templates programmatically (i.e. xlApp.Workbooks.Open("path??")) once they have been installed with my project on a users computer
3. how/where to save new versions of the templates on a users computer once filled with data

I've tried adding them as project resources but running into several difficulties:

1. in code resource is always typed as byte[]??? MyProgram.Properties.Resources.testbook
2. resources don't appear anywhere in user installation files despite having set 'build action' to 'Content' and 'copy to output directory' as 'copy always'

Any better ideas very welcome

Answer (score 0):

Ah ok I understand what everyone else online is talking about now, I did not understand at first:

1. Saving as resource seems to be the best way to go
2. you must save a resource locally before you can use it. This has been pointed out and described by a multitude of people online. The below saves the file to temp files.

   ```
       string tpath = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
       System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(tpath, Properties.Resources.testbook);
   ```
3. you can then simply access you file via the file name "tpath"

Answer (score 0):

You can add code to copy the template file from a shared location to user's storage in his laptop. Then when you make any changes, you can copy the new template file to local storage again.